# Different imputation approaches for different numeric columns using Pycaret 3.0

Tags: pycaret

I need to specify different imputation approaches for different columns using Pycaret 3.0. I couldn't find a solution in Pycaret docs but when I ask ChatGPT, it mentions this code which does not work:

```
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
from pycaret.classification import *

# load the Titanic dataset
titanic = get_data('titanic')

# set up the PyCaret environment
clf = setup(data=titanic, target='Survived', numeric_imputation={
    'Age': 'mean',  # impute missing values in column 'Age' with mean
    'Fare': 'median',  # impute missing values in column 'Fare' with median
    'Pclass': 3,  # impute missing values in column 'Pclass' with 3
    'SibSp': 'zero',  # impute missing values in column 'SibSp' with zero
    'Parch': 'interpolate'  # impute missing values in column 'Parch' using interpolation
})
```

The error I get is:

ValueError: 'fill_value'={'Age': 'mean', 'Fare': 'median', 'Pclass': 3, 'SibSp': 'zero', 'Parch': 'interpolate'} is invalid. Expected a numerical value when imputing numerical data

How do I specify different imputation approaches for different numeric columns using Pycaret 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, it does not seem to be possible to set the imputation type on the feature to feature basis. You can only set one for type for numerical features and another for categorical.

If you ask ChatGPT for something that cannot be done, at least not easily, it will sometimes tend to hallucinate a solution that seems plausible but is made up.

Answer (score 0):

For **numeric imputation**, you can use: drop, mean, median, mode, knn, int or float.

[pycaret.gitbook.io - Data Preparation](https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/get-started/preprocessing/data-preparation)

**PARAMETERS**

**imputation_type:** string, default = 'simple'

The type of imputation to use. It can be either simple or iterative. If None, no imputation of missing values is performed.

**1) numeric_imputation:** int, float, or string, default = ‘mean’
Imputing strategy for numerical columns. Ignored when imputation_type= iterative. Choose from:

**drop:** Drop rows containing missing values.

**mean:** Impute with mean of column.

**median:** Impute with median of column.

**mode:** Impute with most frequent value.

**knn:** Impute using a K-Nearest Neighbors approach.

**int or float:** Impute with provided numerical value.

**2) categorical_imputation:** string, default = ‘mode’

Imputing strategy for categorical columns. Ignored when imputation_type= iterative. Choose from:

**drop:** Drop rows containing missing values.

**mode:** Impute with most frequent value.

**str:** Impute with provided string.